# How do I paste multi-line bash codes into terminal and run it all at once?

Tags: linux, bash, shell, terminal, paste

I need to paste a multi-line bash code into terminal, but whenever I do, each line gets run as a separate command as soon as it gets pasted.

Answer (score 138, accepted):

Try putting `\` at the end of each line before copying it.

Example:

```sh
echo "Hello world" && \
script_b.sh

echo $?
```

The exit code (`$?`) is now the full sequence of commands, and not just the last command.

Comment: Note: trailing spaces will break it!

Answer (score 100):

I'm really surprised this answer isn't offered here, I was in search of a solution to this question and I think this is the easiest approach, and more flexible/forgiving...

If you'd like to paste multiple lines from a website/text editor/etc., into bash, regardless of whether it's commands per line or a function or entire script... simply start with a `(` and end with a `)` and Enter, like in the following example:

If I had the following blob

```
function hello {
    echo Hello!
}
hello
```

You can paste and verify in a terminal using bash by:

1. Starting with `(`
2. Pasting your text, and pressing Enter (to make it pretty)... or not
3. Ending with a `)` and pressing Enter

Example:

```
imac:~ home$ ( function hello {
>     echo Hello!
> }
> hello
> )
Hello!
imac:~ home$
```

The pasted text automatically gets continued with a prepending `>` for each line. I've tested with multiple lines with commands per line, functions and entire scripts. Hope this helps others save some time!

Comment: easiest method IMO

Comment: @Toolkit for the simple things it will work as you described, but the solution I've offered will work for more complex situations (line breaks, multiple functions, entire scripts, etc.)

Comment: This runs the pasted commands in a subshell, so it often doesn't actually do what you want. You can use braces instead of parentheses to force it to run in the current shell; but really, just don't do either. The shell can cope.

Comment: I also really like this option.

Answer (score 49):

If you press `C-x C-e` command that will open your default editor which defined `.bashrc`, after that you can use all powerful features of your editor. When you save and exit, the lines will wait your enter.

If you want to define your editor, just write for Ex. `EDITOR=emacs -nw` or `EDITOR=vi` inside of `~/.bashrc`

Comment: The technique is useful, but note that the editor must run _synchronously_ (as `emacs` and `vi` do), and on saving and exiting the commands are executed _instantly_.

Answer (score 20):

Add parenthesis around the lines. Example:

```
$ (
sudo apt-get update
dokku apps
dokku ps:stop APP # repeat to shut down each running app
sudo apt-get install -qq -y dokku herokuish sshcommand plugn
dokku ps:rebuildall # rebuilds all applications
)
```

Comment: Do note, like paranthesis `(`, braces `{` would also work the same in the above example

Comment: This seems to duplicate [an earlier answer on this page](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43164204/874188)

Answer (score 20):

Another possibility:

```
bash << EOF
echo "Hello"
echo "World"
EOF
```

Comment: My favored method. Also, check out [this answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/547990/356252) to see how to pipe/redirect when using heredocs

Answer (score 19):

In addition to backslash, if a line ends with `|` or `&&` or `||`, it will be continued on the next line.

Answer (score 7):

To prevent a long line of commands in a text file, I keep my copy-pase snippets like this:

```
echo a;\
echo b;\
echo c
```

Comment: This answer seems to achieve the same as accepted answer with just 2 instead of 3 (&&\) characters. Why is the accepted answer so much preferable?

Answer (score 3):

I'm surprised no one's said this, but you can use [`fc`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fc_(Unix)) to paste all the commands in an editor and run them at once

Comment: An example would be helpful.

Comment: I'm confused what an example would look like? You just type `fc` in the command line

Comment: And what do you do after that?

Comment: You paste all the commands you want to run and that's it. I wish I could give examples, but I think running `fc` in Terminal will show how simple it is

Comment: I run fc but nothing happens

Answer (score 2):

iTerm handles multiple-line command perfectly, it saves multiple-lines command as one command, then we can use `Cmd`+ `Shift` + `;` to navigate the history.

Check more iTerm tips at [Working effectively with iTerm](http://lifelongprogrammer.blogspot.com/2018/06/working-effectively-with-iterm.html)

Answer (score 2):

So I think for very long command (namely compiling a file with llvm!) this has given me the most ease of us over the others Ive tried in the past. I use it all the time to thrash out a command in an editor over multiple lines:

```
cat | paste -sd " "  - | xargs echo
```

This will open up cat standard input in the terminal, paste in the code and follow up with ctrl-d (mentioned before this adds a EOF char and ends CAT process). Paste takes in the cat input and scoops up all multi lines into a space char. This will ONLY echo out the command.

To execute the command just add sh to the end:

```
cat | paste -sd " "  - | xargs echo | sh
```

Or alternatively I like to make the output an alias command, place in .zshrc

```
alias mcmd='cat | paste -sd " "  - | xargs echo'
```

then to execute

```
> mcmd | sh
```

this will open cat, paste in your multi line command, ctrl d and will execute the multi lines as a one line command  :)

## Example command

```
>    mcmd;
# now paste in your long command
> llvm-g++
    main.mm
    -o
    buildApp
    -w
    -g
    -std=c++14
    -L/System/Library/Frameworks/
    -framework
    CoreServices
     # now key press ctrl + d
```

## whoop! outputs single line

```
 llvm-g++ main.mm -o buildApp -w -g -std=c++14 -L/System/Library/Frameworks/ -framework CoreServices
```

Comment: This helped me - I needed to paste a long list of arguments for a single command. I think there's other ways to do it, but this is useful for what I needed.

Answer (score 1):

Try this way:

```
echo $( 
    cmd1
    cmd2
    ...
)
```

Answer (score -1):

Try

```
out=$(cat)
```

Then paste your lines and press Ctrl-D (insert EOF character). All input till Ctrl-D will be redirected to cat's stdout.

Comment: try this: `$ out=$(cat) && eval "$out"`. hit enter after last line then CTRL+D as suggested above.

Answer (score -1):

I have `vi` key bindings set in my shell. I don't recall, offhand, how I configured this. But when entering a command, I can switch from editing into command mode, type `v` and have the command automatically pop up in a `vim` session. Exiting the session (`:wq`) submits the command to `bash` for execution.