# Bash - Version Numbers in Filenames. How to list latest versions only?

Tags: bash, unix

I have a directory of **versioned** files. The version of each file is indicated within it's filename, e.g. "_v1".

**Example**

List of files shown by `ls`:

```
123_FileA_v1.txt
123_FileA_v2.txt
132_FileB_v1.txt
```

I want to run a command to see only the **latest** versions:

```
123_FileA_v2.txt
132_FileB_v1.txt
```

My first attempt was to list files by `mtime` using

```
ls -ltr
```

But in my case this doesn't lead to sufficient results. I really want to collect versions from the filenames.

What would be the best way to do it?

Comment: By the way, question who do not show any effort on solving them on your own are frowned upon on this site. Not to mention you will get downvotes.

Comment: Vote for reopen. New user has ask an okay question. OP is not asking for code. (I see no urging need for own attempt). Question has been edited since close vote.

Comment: Thanks @jschnasse, good to see dissent from the mindless army of "what have you tried" bots.  There are literally dozens of us!  And welcome user12973426, this is an interesting puzzle.

Comment: Thanks all, Sorry it’s my first time posting here I’ll take note of it and show more effort visibly in the future questions

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will do it :

```
ls | awk -F '_' '!prefixes[$1]++'
```

Hope it helps!

#### Edit :

If you want to see specific info you can do :

```
ls | awk -F '_' '!prefixes[$1]++' | xargs ls -lh
```

This will work as long as there are not spaces in your filenames.

#### Edit :

As requested by @PaulHodges, here is the sample output :_

```
$ ls -lh
total 0
drwxr-xr-x    5 Matias-Barrios  Matias-Barrios   160B Feb 27 11:40 .
drwxr-xr-x  106 Matias-Barrios  Matias-Barrios   3.3K Feb 27 11:39 ..
-rw-r--r--    1 Matias-Barrios  Matias-Barrios     0B Feb 27 11:40 132_FileB_v1.txt
-rw-r--r--    1 Matias-Barrios  Matias-Barrios     0B Feb 27 11:40 123_FileA_v2.txt
-rw-r--r--    1 Matias-Barrios  Matias-Barrios     0B Feb 27 11:40 123_FileA_v1.txt
$ ls | awk -F '_' '!prefixes[$1]++' 
.
..
132_FileB_v1.txt
123_FileA_v2.txt
```

Comment: What is it this is supposed to do? For me is doesn't seem to be doing anything more than the `ls`.

Comment: @PaulHodges It works for me. And it dedups the filenames for the given input by OP

Comment: Why `ls` if there is `find` or `for file in *`?

Comment: @Quasímodo I dont know; ask OP.

Comment: Thank you so much for the quick and perfect solution :)

Comment: For some reason it doesn't work for me. Prints: `123_FileA_v1.txt 132_FileB_v1.txt`. Why?

Answer (score 0):

You could do something like

```
( 
PATTERN="[0-9]{3}_[^_]*" 
for prefix in `find . | egrep -o "$PATTERN" | sort -u`; 
do 
   ls $prefix* | tail -1; 
done
)
```

It will print

```
123_FileA_v2.txt
132_FileB_v1.txt
```

**What happens here?**

- The surrounding braces `(` are used to support copy & paste of the provided code. [read more](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6713056)
- The variable `PATTERN` is used to access all files starting with the same prefix.
- The `` for prefix in `find . | egrep -o "$PATTERN" | sort -u `` generates a list of file prefixes.
- The `ls $prefix*` lists all files with the same prefix in alphanumerical order
- The `| tail -1` shows only the last entry of the former `ls $prefix*`

**Edit**

I decided to use `find .` instead of `ls *`. With that I hope to circumvent the [issues with `ls *`](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/128985). Please correct me, if I'm wrong!

Comment: Now do it without [parsing ls](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLshttps://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs).

Comment: Thanks this works but when the file list gets huge it’s seems to get a bit slow possibly due to the ls within the loop